# How to do Method/Field Injection in Scala using Guice?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I am trying to do either method or field injection in Scala. I am using the Play Framework, which uses Guice for injecting. I have tried field injection like:

```scala
@Inject val cache: DefaultSyncCacheApi = null
```

like detailed [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3887), but whenever I try to test it I get a `NullPointerException`. I have also tried method injection, like:

```scala
@Inject
def method(id: String, cache: DefaultSyncCacheApi): Boolean = {
   val cachedItem = cache.get(id)
   cachedItem.isDefined
}
```

to no avail either. I would have to pass in the cache from another place as well.

I have also tried to use overloaded methods and injecting separately, such as:

```scala
val cache: DefaultSyncCacheApi //this will not work if it is not an abstract class

@Inject //either injecting here
def methodA(id: String): Boolean = {
   methodB(string, cache)
}

@Inject //or injecting here
def methodB(id: String, cache: DefaultSyncCacheApi): Boolean = {
   //same logic as 'method' above
}
```

to no avail. Is there a clear cut way to do method or field injection without causing an NPE?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that these fields are injected *too early* (before Guice has setup the Application).

So what you can try is to change all `val`s to `lazy val`s.

I have to say I only use Injection in the constructor which works perfectly. Your Example

```
class HomeController @Inject()(id: String, cache: DefaultSyncCacheApi)
```

However for the `id` you will need a Provider in your Module. And as it is a String you should name it. Here an example:

`Module.scala`

```
  @Provides
  @Named("myIdentitfier")
  def provideId(): String = {
    IdCreator.nextId().
  }
```

`HomeController.scala`

```
class HomeController @Inject()(@Named("myIdentitfier") id: String, cache: DefaultSyncCacheApi)
```

Comment: FYI, doing it lazyily did not work. I would also prefer to do it via the constructor, but this class is being instantiated elsewhere and would require injecting the cache throughout the whole system to pass it down to this single spot where it is needed right now. Is there a way to use constructor injection when it is being instantiated elsewhere?

Comment: You can do it in the Module -  like I demonstrated with "myIdentifier". See https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods